# Sql Query to get an item that contains multiple ids from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

I have three tables.
Container, Inventory and SKU

Container table

| ContainerId |
| --- |
| C1 |
| C2 |
| C3 |

Inventory Table

| InventoryId | Sku | Container |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | S1 | C1 |
| I2 | S1 | C2 |
| I3 | S2 | C1 |

SKU Table

| SkuId |
| --- |
| S1 |
| S2 |
| S3 |

I need to create a sql query that will return the container(s) that contains all of the given SKU ids.
So if I want the containers that have SKU S1, my results should be C1 and C2
but if I want to get the containers that have SKU ids S1 and S2 my only result should be C1. C2 should not be a result because it does not have S2.

So far the query I have tried is

```
SELECT distinct containerId FROM Container c 
   JOIN Inventory i ON i.Container = c.ContainerId
   JOIN SKU s ON s.SkuId = i.Sku
   WHERE s.SkuId IN (S1, S2)
```

But the WHERE IN statement is a shorthanded OR so it will return C2 as a result too because it contains S1.

I know there is no way to shorthand an AND condition but is there a similar way or a possible way to do this?

Comment: *SELECT distinct c FROM Container c* - table Container doesn't have a column `c` so this will give an error?

Comment: I meant containerId, I fixed the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of distinct, you use group by and use count to verify that all required skus were present:

```
SELECT c.ContainerId
FROM Container c 
JOIN Inventory i ON i.Container = c.ContainerId
JOIN SKU s ON s.SkuId = i.Sku AND s.SkuId in (S1, S2)
GROUP BY c.ContainerId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.SkuId)=2
```

But, as commented by others, there's no need to use any table but Inventory:

```
SELECT i.Container
FROM Inventory i
WHERE i.Sku in (S1, S2)
GROUP BY i.Container
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.Sku)=2
```

Comment: And, it has to be said, you only need to query the `Inventory` table. JOINing the other tables doesn't do much, because you're only processing the id values.

Comment: What if I want to get the whole Container row and not just the Id? I was trying before the group by condition as 
SELECT c.* from Container C [...] GROUP BY c.* but it does not let you do that

Comment: you only need to group by i.Container or c.ContainerId

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need any joins for this query, for the results you specify in the question:

```
SELECT i.Container
FROM Inventory i 
WHERE i.Sku in (S1, S2)
GROUP BY i.Container
HAVING COUNT(i.Sku) = 2;
```

You only need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` if a container could have multiple rows for the same `SkuId`.